# Nook Comics on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios

I'm considering buying an iPad to read comics, so I am looking in to my options for purchasing digital comics.  I see Barnes and Noble sells "Nook Comics", and their site indicates these can be read on the color Nook tablets and the Nook app for Android.

Seems odd that they'd support reading the comics on the Nook app only for Android, not under iOS as well.  I was hoping someone who uses the Nook ecosystem and has an iPad could clarify if this is an oversight, or accurate.  Does the iPad Nook app really not support Nook Comics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest release of NOOK for iPad and iPhone now supports comics and manga.

Comment: Please add in the version of nook that supports comics. Adding that will help people know if they have the "newest" once several months have gone by.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert from the Nook format (which I believe is special for the Nook) to one which is more general purpose. The first obstacle is, what exactly is the format they come in?

The chances are very good that you can find something to convert it to PDF, for free.

Once it is in PDF or CBZ or CBR or some more common format, there are lots of comic readers for iPad - my favourite is Comic Zeal but iBooks works pretty well too for PDF.

Comment: I'm not looking to break the DRM on the Nook comics and convert them into other formats.  I'm trying to find out if they can be read on an iPad.

Comment: My answer is no, not without breaking DRM. It's a shame but that's DRM - http://paidcontent.org/2012/04/24/breaking-drm-publishing-exec/ - if I buy it I need to know I can un-DRM it, because it is very unlikely I'll read exclusively on a Nook for the rest of my life.

Comment: Reading more about the Kindle, Nook, and Comixology digital comic options available, I'm not sure this answer is feasible.  All these platforms require you to view the comics on an app, so you'd need to get the files by rooting/hacking/jailbreaking the device and digging through the file system.  Comixology is the only one that lets you view the comics on a computer, and you do so inside a Flash program.